# C++ child class extends the parent class

Tags: c++

There is a parent class, and there are two child class extends the parent class: child1,child2, I see the children as parent class, like this:

```
function(Parent *c){
  c->someMethod();
}
```

but child has a method which child2 doesn't have. I try to add a if statement to judge whether the class is child1 like this:

```
function(Parent *c){
  if(c->getType() == 'child1'){
     c->someMethod();
  }
}
```

but there comes the error:'class Parent' has no member named 'someMethod' so, how to deal with it?

Comment: The obvious answer is, "you cast". The *correct* answer is, "you revisit your design because it's incorrectly using polymorphism".

Comment: [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is a possible redesign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are working with pointer to `Parent`, you can only call methods, which `Parent` type have.

So, the first solution is to put all necessary methods in `Parent` class and override them in children classes. This is far more preferable than next one.

Another possible solution is to `dynamic_cast` `Parent` pointer to necessary `child` pointer, if you are sure, that it's correct one and call method on `child` pointer. This is sign of bad design, and I'd recommend to stick to first solution.

Comment: If you are **sure**, than you can use `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

Try dynamic_casting it to the correct type. If it is not possible, the cast should return a nullptr (or NULL).